# Bash re-run case statement until user inputs NO

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this piece of code which asks the user a simple `yes/no`.
The thing here, it should be to re-execute the code until the user explicitly says `no`.

With the following code, only one instance of `yes` is executed, then it exits.

```
while true; do
  read -p "Do you wish to continue with the analysis? " yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) 
            read -p 'Provide the folder to analyze: ' newFolderToAnalyze
             
            if [ -d "$newFolderToAnalyze" ]; then
              du -h $newFolderToAnalyze --max-depth=1 
            fi    
                 
            break
            ;;
    [Nn]* )
            echo -e 'Bye-bye cause you said it!'
            ;;
    * ) 
            echo "Please answer yes or no."
            ;;
  esac
done
```

The key here, is that when the user inputs the `yes` the program **should ask him again**, until he says `no`.

Note the `break` statement, is there something to similar to end the current execution and jump to the while loop again?

Comment: replace the `break` with `continue`

Comment: That's it @HaraldGliebe thanks. Gonna update the question

Answer (score 1):

You can stick the prompt and its evaluation into the condition:

```sh
while read -rp 'Continue? ' && [[ $REPLY != [Nn]* ]]; do
    echo "analyzing..."
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your script as follow:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to continue with the analysis? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) 
            read -p 'Provide the folder to analyze: ' newFolderToAnalyze
         
            if [ -d "$newFolderToAnalyze" ] 
            then
            
                du -h $newFolderToAnalyze --max-depth=1 
           
            fi    
        ;;
        
        [Nn]* )
            echo -e 'Bye-bye cause you said it!'
            break
        ;;
        
        * ) 
            echo "Please answer yes or no."
        ;;
    esac
done
```